# PHP: how to get a backtrace automatically without calling debugging functions

Tags: php

Im wondering if there is any way to get/write a backtrace to a file without using any function. **I mean**: to get a backtrace using the function [debug_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-backtrace.php) you have to *call it*. So to get get a backtrace you have to know *where* to call `debug_backtrace()`. In my case I'm getting and error `Allowed memory size of..` so I don't know what is the function that is being called just before the error to call the function `debug_backtrace()`..

Comment: wha? .. o.O so using debug_backtrace() in the file with the `allowed memory size of` error returns nothing?

Comment: If the path following the given error doesn't help, you have to use a profiler.

Comment: xdebug might be a better way to go ^^

Comment: hmmm ... isnt that the purpose of `try{ //some code} } catch(\Exception $e){ // your backtrace here }`;